# Find rows with subset of values in another DataFrame, in a vectorized way

Tags: python, pandas

How to match values from this DataFrame `source`:

```
     car_id     lat     lon
0    100        10.0    15.0
1    100        12.0    10.0
2    100        09.0    08.0
3    110        23.0    12.0
4    110        18.0    32.0
5    110        21.0    16.0
5    110        12.0    02.0
```

And keep only those whose coords are in this second DataFrame `coords`:

```
     lat     lon
0    12.0    10.0
1    23.0    12.0
3    18.0    32.0
```

So that the resulting DataFrame `result` is:

```
     car_id     lat     lon
1    100        12.0    10.0
3    110        23.0    12.0
4    110        18.0    32.0
```

I can do that in an iterative way with `apply`, but I'm looking for a vectorized way. I tried the following with `isin()` with no success:

```
result = source[source[['lat', 'lon']].isin({
    'lat': coords['lat'],
    'lon': coords['lon']
})]
```

The above method returns:

```
ValueError: ('operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (53103,) (53103,2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[DataFrame.merge()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) per default merges on all columns with the same names (intersection of the columns of both DFs):

```
In [197]: source.merge(coords)
Out[197]:
   car_id   lat   lon
0     100  12.0  10.0
1     110  23.0  12.0
2     110  18.0  32.0
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's one approach with [`NumPy broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
a = source.values
b = coords.values
out = source[(a[:,1:]==b[:,None]).all(-1).any(0)]
```

Sample run -

```
In [74]: source
Out[74]: 
   car_id   lat   lon
0     100  10.0  15.0
1     100  12.0  10.0
2     100   9.0   8.0
3     110  23.0  12.0
4     110  18.0  32.0
5     110  21.0  16.0
5     110  12.0   2.0

In [75]: coords
Out[75]: 
    lat   lon
0  12.0  10.0
1  23.0  12.0
3  18.0  32.0

In [76]: a = source.values
    ...: b = coords.values
    ...: 

In [77]: source[(a[:,1:]==b[:,None]).all(-1).any(0)]
Out[77]: 
   car_id   lat   lon
1     100  12.0  10.0
3     110  23.0  12.0
4     110  18.0  32.0
```